# Node.js not recognizing .env file

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I have multiple Node.js services running, but I have a problem in one of those.

This is the `nodemon.json` file:

```
{
  "watch": ["**/*.ts"],
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "ignore": ["./test/*.ts"],
  "exec": "node -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config Index.ts dotenv_config_path=$(pwd)/.env",
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  }
}
```

It's the same as the rest of services. When I run `npm run dev` I got error messages depending on which value is taking from the .env file, example:

```
const LOCAL_CONFIGURATION = {
    PORT_APP: 8082,
    MONGODB: {
        SERVER: process.env.MONGO_DTE,
        AUTH: {
            auth: {
                password:process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD,
                user:process.env.MONGO_USER
            }
        },
    },
    MS_NOTIFICACION: "http://localhost:8089/notificacion",
    ELASTIC_PATH: process.env.ELASTIC_PATH,
    ...COMMON,
};
```

The first error message is:
`ConfigurationError: Missing node(s) option`
That message is produced because it's not reading the value from `process.env.ELASTIC_PATH`, but if I put a hardcoed value like "http://with.the.correct.url" and it tries again to run, I get another error:

`Error: Credentials must be provided when creating a service client`
That error is because it's trying to read `password:process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD` and `user:process.env.MONGO_USER`

etc, so, there's a problem on reading the `.env` file. I know that `.env` file has those values, and the file is in UTF-8, without quotes, etc. The `.env` file is the same file as the other services, it works OK in the rest but I don't know why is not getting read here.

Any idea?

[image]

Plus, I put a  `console.log(process.env);` in `config.ts` file and it shows values like this:

[image]

But there's no values from the `.env` for example, there in the picture there's a value called `COMPUTERNAME` so if I put `console.log(process.env.COMPUTERNAME);` I get: `IBM-NOT87`

Why is not getting the .env file?

Comment: would you please show me your .env file and where its located

Comment: At the root of the app. Ok, I will edit que question with some part of the file with also a comment

Comment: require('dotenv').config();
 add in thse files where you are trying to access env fie. And access like thisprocess.env.NODE_ENV  And must install 'dotenv'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems like you need to require/configure `dotenv`. [Docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage):

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.
>
> `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: Where should I put that? sorry, first day with nodejs, I've been like 12 hours installing this 12 microservices... this is the only one with the problem

Comment: Ideally the entry point in your app, sometimes named `app.js`. This will load your `.env` into `process.env`.

Comment: It is suposs to be registered here: `exec": "node -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config Index.ts dotenv_config_path=$(pwd)/.env",` that's script is called `nodemon` it is run by `npm start dev`

Comment: Man... I don't get it. The rest of the microservices don't have actually that string when I search it in the entire folders. But I put that line in the very first part of Index.js, and now it works. I really don't get it.

Comment: Index.js is great! Glad it works. I’m not positive how that exec script works. Regarding the other microservices, have you tried searching for all instances of “dotenv” - there are other ways to require/configure it.

Answer (score 6):

To further expand on @JBallin answer, you need to **require/import** dotenv config in the file where you want to use Environment Variables

```js
// for example in your index.js or app.js

require('dotenv').config()
// or
require('dotenv/config') 


// if using ES6 module imports
import 'dotenv/config'
```

Answer (score 5):

`require('dotenv').config({ path: "./sample.env" });`

In the file you are using environment variables,
As early as possible, require the `"dotenv"` and in the `config()` method, specify the path of the `.env` file, even if it in your root directory or the same directory where node starts.

The code for requiring and specifying file in the same directory is in the first line in the answer.

Also, for further reading  , you can visit https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path

Answer (score 2):

You cat try this.

-> npm i dotenv

and in code add this piece of code

```
require('dotenv').config({
    path: 'your path here'
})
```

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038634/14267427).

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2023 - node no longer needs external software to read .env files

[node.js `20.6.0` includes built-in support for .env files](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V20.md#built-in-env-file-support)

```
node --env-file='.env'
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new update, you would just need to add this comnand line in your package json file:

```
node --env-file='.env'
```

Comment: This seems like the same answer I already gave above.

Answer (score 0):

Install dotenv package

> npm install --s dotenv

And add this `require("dotenv").config();` in index.js/ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Just add --env-file=.env in you script.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "--env-file=.env app.js"
  },
```