# expo create app for web does not initialize environmental variables

Tags: expo

step to reproduce:

1. npm install -g expo-cli
2. expo init my-new-project // select blank template
3. create .env file in the root
4. create single entry REACT_APP_TEST_URL=https://example.com
5. in App console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_TEST_URL);
6. yarn web

result:
log prints undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you expect your code to populate `process.env` with the contents of your `.env` file? You don't seem to have followed [the instructions](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/#dotenv).

Comment: because I do this for the first time, I don't have app.config.js in the project and setting extra in json by accessing process.env does not make sense to me. Inlining with babel is not preferred option as well. Besides this is react app and the popular approach is to do it as I'm trying in the code above

Comment: "Inlining with babel is not preferred" — That isn't the section I linked to (which is lower down).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS not recognizing .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038365/nodejs-not-recognizing-env-file)

Comment: Nope, I don't see how it's connected even. On my nodejs server I use dotenv package and I dont have any problems reading the environment. Trying to install the package in the client  would not work as dotenv has references to nodejs modules os and path at least .

Comment: You've got to do *something* to read the `.env` file and expose it to your client-side JS. There are various frameworks which will use dotenv to do that. The documentation for expo implies that its default set up *won't* do that.